# Slight delay when receiving data from Firestore - any way to speed up or smooth?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, delay

I have a flutter app which uses Firestore as a database. When a user has no data a page is displayed with a message

**'Add some products'**

If the user has data they see a list of their products.

The problem I have is when I click out of this tab and return to it, for a fraction of a second (approx. 0.3 seconds) the message saying 'Add some products' is displayed, then it retrieves the data and displays the list of products.

I am looking for a way to either remove this delay, or just make the transition smoother.

Answer (score 1):

You can't realistically remove the delay of a Firestore query.  It's always going to take some unknown amount of time to query the database, the amount of time mostly depending on the quality of the network connection between the client and the server.  If you're depending on cached results, it will still take time to load documents from disk.

Your app should initially display some sort of loading indicator (or even nothing at all) until the query generates data to act on.  If you want to be able to return to the screen without any delay, you're going to have to cache the results of the query in memory for reuse.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into caching and just display a loading symbol for now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to speed up... because the query data return depends on a lot of factor including internet speed. So other users may get an increased than only 0.3 sec. It's better to use a `FutureBuilder` for futures.

eg :
like this;

```
FutureBuilder(
     future: Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName').document(docId).get(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.exits){
    return Text('Add items'); //yourWidget to add items 

    }if else (snapshot.exits){
     return YourWidget(); //your widget which shows the items
  }else{

  return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
 }
)
```